# node-gyp build error while installing raw-socket

Tags: node.js, linker, makefile, flock

I am trying to install net-ping module on my nodejs but I get a strange error in the raw-socket installation phase.

I had the same `flock` problem when I was compiling nodejs source code for installation, but I added `LINK=g++ make` and the problem was solved. Is there any way to solve this?!

---

I tried alias='LINK=g++ make' but it didn't work!

```
$ npm install net-ping
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/net-ping
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/net-ping
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-socket

> raw-socket@1.1.4 install /root/projectsrc/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/projectsrc/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
  g++ '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/root/.node-gyp/0.8.23/src -I/root/.node-gyp/0.8.23/deps/uv/include -I/root/.node-gyp/0.8.23/deps/v8/include  -Wall -pthread -m32 -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-tree-vrp -fno-tree-sink -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o.d.raw  -c -o Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o ../src/raw.cc
  flock ./Release/linker.lock g++ -shared -pthread -rdynamic -m32  -Wl,-soname=raw.node -o Release/obj.target/raw.node -Wl,--start-group Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o -Wl,--end-group 
./Release/linker.lock: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/raw.node] Error 3
make: Leaving directory `/root/projectsrc/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:680:10)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.11-1.1369_FC4
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/projectsrc/node_modules/net-ping/node_modules/raw-socket
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.23
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! raw-socket@1.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the raw-socket@1.1.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the raw-socket package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls raw-socket
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.11-1.1369_FC4
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "net-ping"
npm ERR! cwd /root/projectsrc
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/projectsrc/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Having this issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

- Ensure you have `python2.7`, `make` and `gcc` installed.
- Use an even-numbered Node version, e. g. `0.10.x` and not odd-numbered, e. g. `0.11.x`.

The latter advice resolved my issue. [Source](https://github.com/fzaninotto/uptime/issues/238#issuecomment-45047164).